# Dfs to find visited nodes in sml

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, sml

What is wrong with this part of code ? I'm trying to make a function which (given a graph) returns a list with all visited nodes, but the compiler keeps saying that there are some erros. Can the code be fixed ?The succesors function is used to find all nodes that are connected to the node which is takes as a parameter. I need dfs function in order to check if the returned "visited" list has all nodes, or in other words if the graph has all nodes connected to each other with a path. -The parameter tuple is a list with tuples of form (weight,node1,node1).

```ml
        fun succesors n e =
         List.map (fn (_,v ,_) => v) (List.filter (fn (u,_,_) => n = u) e)


        fun dfs tuples node start =
         let
          fun find_visited visited node =
           if not (List.exists node visited) then
            let
              val s = (succesors node tuples)
            in
              List.foldl find_visited (node::visited) s
            end
           else visited
         in
           find_visited [] start
          end
```

Those were the errors that were printed :

```
      ask2_ml.sml:75.18-75.39 Error: operator and operand don't agree 
      [equality type required]
      operator domain: ''Z
      operand:         'Y -> bool
      in expression:
      succesors node
      ask2_ml.sml:77.35-77.48 Error: operator and operand don't agree 
      [circularity]
      operator domain: ('Z -> bool) * ('Z -> bool) list
      operand:         ('Z -> bool) * 'Z list
      in expression:
      node :: visited
      ask2_ml.sml:72.7-79.16 Error: case object and rules don't agree [tycon 
      mismatch]
      rule domain: _ list * (_ -> bool)
      object: (_ * _) * 'Z
     in expression:
     (case (arg,arg)
      of (visited,node) =>
           if not (<exp> <exp>)
           then let val <binding> in <exp> <exp> end
           else visited)
       ask2_ml.sml:81.3-81.24 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon 
     mismatch]
     operator domain: _ * _
     operand:         'Z list
    in expression:
    find_visited nil

     uncaught exception Error
      raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:292.17-292.20
```

Comment: If the weight is the first component of items in `tuples`, shouldn't it be `List.map (fn (_,_,v) => v) (List.filter (fn (_,u,_) => n = u) e)` in `successors`?

Comment: Type of `successor` is `val succesors = fn: ''a -> (''a * 'b * 'c) list -> 'b list`... which is to say, a function that takes a value of type `''a`, and then takes a value of type `List of triples(3-Tuple)`, to return a `List` of `'b`(s).

Comment: Type of `List.exists` is `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool`... which is to say that it takes a `function` as first parameter(a function that takes a value of type `'a` and returns a `bool), then a second parameter of type `List of 'a`, to finally return a `bool` as it's result. And the point at which it is invoked, is having wrong type of arguments.

Comment: First try and fix these 2... where in the call to `successor` happens indirectly through a recursive application of `find_visited`.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems in your code.

First, `List.exists` is defined as:

```ml
val exists : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool
```

So `List.exists node visited` is incorrect as `node` is not a
function.  You should instead do something like `List.exists (fn n => n = node) visited`.

Second, `List.foldl` is defined as:

```ml
val foldl : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

Here again `List.foldl find_visited (node::visited) s` is incorrect since
`find_visited` is of type `'a -> 'b -> 'a`.

By fixing these two issues I get the following:

```ml
fun successors n e =
   List.map (fn (_,v ,_) => v) (List.filter (fn (u,_,_) => n = u) e);

fun dfs tuples node start = let
   fun find_visited (node, visited) =
      if List.exists (fn n => n = node) visited
      then visited
      else let
         val s = successors node tuples
      in
         List.foldl find_visited (node::visited) s
      end
in
   find_visited (start, [])
end;
```

On a side note, it's extremely inefficient to implement `visited` as a
list: each time you meet a node you will look at all previously
visited nodes to check if it's new (`List.exists`).  Same for your
implementation of your successor relation: traversing all edges of
your graph to find the successors of `n` will be too slow.

Comment: Plus 1. How about if you can also drop a hint for him about the `visited` remark.